# Identify hash pattern inside a string

Tags: hash, sha256

I believe that this question was answered already, though I couldn't find it.

I have several strings that include hash. Each string has hash and some random (or not) add-on.
How can I identify the type of hash that is hidden inside a string?

```
43310077472A7FF4BD986765FB830F9C5BC0BDAC3B0941847D76771A824FF3CFE7B4BF46

4331075347C312F3B5C51A428D6BDF7C3D629DA043D6C33670DC84BF4A8B4706DC678A53

433106821A38503238A37BC8371E44BFD66BADFB45BBFA46F86BBEDA2A9A5D8A0879B0F0


4331069061307C256AF1AC9B412FEB4B20DB48E736F4856809FDE6F807EE6F931A8C468B

433107461FC5F8D4FCEB31185D9262E9FC6A2EE22FD98A81E8F391645A8618D0CBD96297
```

Comment: I don't think it is possible to understand hashing functions used just looking at string. You have to go through reverse engineering process

Comment: Not exactly. The assumption is that sha string = password is not applicable in my case. Some of the string is hash and some of it some other data. It's mixed

Comment: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/105438/how-can-i-detect-if-hashes-are-salted

Comment: what you expect is not possible. Only solution is reverse Engineering....